# Updating MS word document dynamically from 2 other documents

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

I'm using MS Word 2010.

I've 3 word documents A, B and C. C is the master document.

Normally I make changes to document A and B and then copy them over to document C (Master Document).

Is there is a way where when I make changes in document A or B and those changes gets dynamically updated in Document C (master document).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but the method depends on how you want the content from documents A and B distributed throughout document C.

If C should consist of all of A, preceded or followed by all of B, you have 2 options (the 2nd of which is slightly more user-friendly):

- Create C as a master document, and then insert A and B as subdocuments. On the **View** tab, in the **Views** group, click **Outline**. Then, in **Outline** view, in the **Master Document** group, click **Show Document** and then **Insert** to insert the first file as a linked file. Repeat for the second file.
- On the **Insert** tab,  in the **Text** group, click the drop-down arrow on the **Object** button, and then click **Text from File**. Select the first file, click the drop-down arrow on the **Insert** button, and then click **Insert as Link**. Repeat for the second file.

If C should consist of a chunk of text from A, then a chunk from B, then another chunk A, and so on:

1. Insert bookmarks in A and B to mark out the various chunks. Select all the text for one chunk in one file, and then, on the **Insert** tab, in the **Links** group, click **Bookmark**, and enter a name for the bookmark. Repeat for all other chunks that you need to break A and B into.
2. In C, follow the steps for the second option above, but when you're selecting the file to insert as a link, click **Range**, and then enter the name of the bookmark for the first chunk. Repeat for every other chunk that you need to include for each file.

When you make changes in A or B, if you used the **Master Document** approach above, the changes will be updated automatically in C the next time that you open it (though to see this, you'll first have to switch to **Outline** view and click **Expand Documents**; otherwise, you'll just see a bunch of hyperlinks). If you used the **Text as File** approach, you have to manually update field codes in C before those changes show up (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all, and then press <kbd>F9</kbd>).

*Update:* **Text from File** inserts an `INCLUDETEXT` field. If your document A and/or B contains fields such as date fields that shouldn't be updated when the content is inserted into C, unless you explicitly update them in A/B, there's a `!\` switch that you can add. This is explained on [the Office Support page about the field code](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Field-codes-IncludeText-field-1c34d6d6-0de3-4b5c-916a-2ff950fb629e).

Comment: cnread thank you for your time. I shall be going with the option 2 and will update you with the progress. Thanking you again for your time